# Why UI freezes?

Tags: java, multithreading

I wont to run my thread in background but it keeps blocking UI. 
In methods `login()` and `dostaff()` I use selenium webdriver to get data and display it in label, after that I refresh page and thread sleeps for 60000ms;

```
public static class Moderate implements Runnable {

public void run() {
    login();
    while (true) {
        dostaff();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
private void login(){....};
private void dostaff(){....};
}
```

and I call it:

```
public void ModerateLoop(javafx.scene.control.Label lbl) {
    this.displayLabel = lbl;
    Moderate thread = new Moderate();
    thread.run();
}
```

Comment: because your while loop is basically an infinite loop, keeping everything occupied

Comment: Thread thread  = new Thread(new Moderate());
thread.start();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you are calling the method run

```
thread.run();
```

so this is blocking the invoking thread until your code in the run method is done.

you need instead to ***start*** the thread

```
thread.start();
```